# Contradictory errors on C++ Class (it is and it is not a const variable)

Tags: c++, arrays, class, constants

I have a class where I define my variable "int _remaining = 52;"
When I try to create an array inside of by class method Deck::shuffle() using this variable I get an error. I can only assign const.

So I tried to add a temporary const variable "const int n = Deck::_remaining" and try to create my array with array[n][2]

My compiler stills complain that it is not const.

So I try to do a "++n;" just to test it. And here I got a contradictory error that now my "n" is const...

What am I missing?

Many thanks!

```
class Deck {
     int _remaining = 52;

public:
     Deck();

}

void Deck::shuffle_deck() {

    const int n = Deck::_remaining; // creating a const tmp value
    n++;  // Error that n is a const (I expected that)
    char* deck_tmp[n][2]; // Error that n cannot be assigned since it is not a const

}
```

Comment: Standard C++ does not allow VLA:s. Use `std::vector`s instead

Comment: And please format your code properly (like I just did for you, but you reverted it)

Comment: I suspect you are misreading the error.  But since you did not post the error *verbatim*, it's difficult to say for sure.

Comment: A "core constant expression" is not the same thing as a "`const` variable"

Comment: If this had worked, you'd be fine: `constexpr int n = Deck::_remaining;`